# WiFi connection after resume from Hibernate

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, hibernate, power-management

My Windows 10 laptop uses the following power options for "Wireless Adapter Settings":

[image]

If I hibernate the laptop and return later, I typically find that the WiFi adapter is no longer connected.  I noticed that if I wait for a few minutes, the WiFi will reconnect.

Is there any way to prevent Windows from disconnecting the adapter when I hibernate?
Is there a way to speed up the reconnection for the adapter?

Comment: Try sleep mode instead?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Yup, already tried that.  Same results.